# Laravel 9.* belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have DB structure:

```
user
    user_id
    
office
    office_id

property
    property_id
    
office_user
    office_user_id
    office_id
    user_id
    
office_user_property
    office_user_id
    property_id
```

Is there way to acess to Property model from User model via belongsToMany?

Comment: Did you define a relation between the two models ? it should be something like : `$this->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'office_user_property', 'office_user_id', 'property_id')`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `hasManyThrough`
(https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), but it only work for one connection in between, and you have two.

What you could do is define a `hasManyThrough` relation between user and office_user_property and define a `hasOne` relation between office_user_property and property

Answer (score 0):

`belongsToMany` refers to [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). This relationship for your case defines that has many properties, while a property is owened by many users. In a nutshell three database tables can be used to define this relationship. `properties` table, `users` table, and `user_property` table. where the `user_property` table contains `user_id` and `property_id` columns.

In the `user` model, the relationship can be defined as:

```
/.../  
public funciton properties(){
      return $this->belonsToMany('App\Property'); 
    }
```

To access properties for a user:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
 
foreach ($user->properties as $property) {
    //
}
```

Ref: [Laravel 5.2 Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)